# Backbone: How to talk to backend without the use of model.save()?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, backbone.js, express

What would be the best way to talk to my backend (node.js/express.js) from backbone without using the .save() method that is tied with the model. 
Basically, I want to check the given user's value on the "server" side and only after getting a success response from the server, I would commit to saving that model with given input.

Any workaround to this problem? best practices?
Do I really have to make my own raw ajax call to node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[model.save()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) allows options to be passed, one of which is `{wait: true}` which will not change the attributes on the model until it receives a response.